# How can I remove small paint specks from a wooden floor?

Tags: painting, paint, repainting

The painters I had hired (and quickly fired) to repaint my apartment spilled some paint (little specks and spots) on the wooden floors and let it dry off without cleaning it.

The paint was "glycéro", which I think translates to alkyd paint. It wasn't acrylic paint.

Since it's dry, I can't remove it with white spirit. I can remove it with paint remover but it also removes the transparent coating on the wooden floor ("vitrification" in french, not sure how to translate it).

Any ideas of what I can try to remove the white dots on my floor without having to redo my floors afterward?

Comment: If the paint spots are very small, you could use a fingernail to scrape them off.

Answer (score 2):

Try some very fine steel wool, #0000 should do it. Confine it to the paint spots only, as best you can. You may try using small amounts of the spirit you tried with that. If the wool dulls the shine of the floor finish test an area first and apply wax over the treated area when done to restore the luster. You could also try automotive scratch removing compound. Use a little bit on a rag and buff the paint out.

Comment: I'll try that and post results.